# How to navigate from one component to another component present in 2 different projects in angular

Tags: angular, module, shared

I have 2 different Angular projects existing in the same workspace.

One with project name as `cards` and component name is `InquiryComponent`.

[image]

The other project name with `cs-leave-inquiry` and component name as `LeaveInquiryComponent`.

[image]

Now I want to access the component `LeaveInquiryComponent` inside `InquiryComponent`. Is this possible using shared modules?

Answer (score 0):

Since these are two different projects, you can create a `SharedModule` and then move the `LeaveInquiryComponent` in the `SharedModule` and export it from there. You probably will have to package it as a node_module.

Once you do that, you can then import that `SharedModule` in both of your projects' modules(In a module that you want to use this in)

Comment: I have created a module for both the pjts and imported the inquirymodule to the cards pjt. Now I am getting related to the files present in assets folder.  since I have translate pipe used for localization, its throwing errors. How to import the assets folder to the pjt. If i place a plain html tag, it works fine.